# BigQuery get the query data

Tags: google-bigquery

We have BigQuery instances with various datasets for each datasets we want to monitor the usage, like number of queries per datasets, queries fired for each datasets, number of users accessing the datasets.

Is there any way in which we can monitor BigQuery usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views have all the information you required.
Try the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_*` for all the information.

**Reference:**

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs